# Android SDK tools setup "Application error"

Tags: android, sdk, windows-xp, installation, java

I'm trying to install the Android SDK tools on my Windows XP SP3. I have `jdk1.5.0_06`  installed, but the Android SDK setup refuses to with the error in the following image. This happes in the next screen after detecting the JDK instalation.

Is this a known issue? And is there a solution?

[image: SDK Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about what the error is. But strongly recommend that you go with JDK 1.6.x version or 1.7x for Android development.

Comment: Only use JDK 1.6, 1.7 is not qualified.

Answer (score 0):

download the installer again & see if it solves the issue. Before installing Android SDK, make sure you have jdk installed on your system. Alternatively you can install eclipse adt plugin & it will automatically install the Android SDK for you. [Installing the Eclipse Plugin](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html)